# Getting RecordTypes and Layouts in LWC for Event/Task?

Tags: lightning-web-components, page-layout, record-type, tasks, event

I am a developer working on a custom LWC component that is made to be used in Outlook via the email application pane and as a mobile page. In the application, one of the features is the ability for users to create new entity records. Currently I have support for creating entities such as Leads, Contact, etc. via lightning-record-form. I also created a custom component for creating Event and Task records via pre-determined fields, since they aren't supported by the UI API and LDS.

Now I want to support adding record type selection to my components. For standard sObjects, I believe I can use getObjectInfo to pull the available record types for a given sObject, allow the user to pick from the record types, and then pass the recordTypeId into lightning-record-form. This is where I run into an issue. I can't use UI API methods or LDS to get record types and layouts for Task and Event record types. I tried using the Salesforce REST API to get the data, but because I am running in an LWC, my sessionId cannot be used for API calls. I am stuck with how to proceed. Is there any way to pull Event/Task layout information into LWC so I can build the UI myself?

Comment: Am working on a similar case. Did you have the answer.
Best regards

Comment: Edit 1/23/24: So the solution I have arrived at is to create a connected app with named and external credentials in the org I was working out of, and then use the Salesforce REST API in Apex to get the layout data eg. [req.setEndpoint('callout:[name_of_named_credential]' +'/services/data/' + API_VERSION + '/sobjects/' + entityType + '/describe/layouts/']. From the layout data, I then wrote several custom components that parse the layout JSON into various lightning inputs. Essentially after getting the layout data, I had to manually recreate the <lightning-record-form> component.